# Servicestack allow same email for multiple users

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to allow multiple users to have the same email.  I extended the OrmLiteAuthRepository overrode the AssertNoExistingUser but it is never called, even though i get the "duplicate email error". I know its hooked up because the getpermissions method is working.

```
    public class MyOrmLiteAuthRepository : OrmLiteAuthRepository
    {
        public MyOrmLiteAuthRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory) : base(dbFactory) { }

        public MyOrmLiteAuthRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory, string namedConnnection = null)
            : base(dbFactory, namedConnnection)
        {
            DbFactory = dbFactory;
            NamedConnnection = namedConnnection;
        }

        protected override void AssertNoExistingUser(IDbConnection db, IUserAuth newUser, IUserAuth exceptForExistingUser = null)
        {
            //I hate using try catch for simple stuff, it is very slow,
            //But this is only during new users being added so low risk for slow
            //and the base class should be called to do its native stuff
            try
            {
                base.AssertNoExistingUser(db,newUser);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.Message.Contains("Email"))
                {
                    //mask duplicate email messages
                    return;
                }
                //throw any other errors on new user creation.
                throw;
            }
        }

public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }
        public string NamedConnnection { get; set; }

        public override ICollection<string> GetPermissions(string userAuthId)
        {
            //Ignore this as we have implemented our own security
            // base.GetPermissions(userAuthId);

            using (var ss = HostContext.ResolveService<SecurityService>(new BasicRequest()))
            {
                return ss.UserPermissions(Convert.ToInt32(userAuthId));
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack can authenticate using either Username or Email, but irrespective of which is used they must be unique in order to uniquely identify the user that is attempting to authenticate.

If you just want to persist the same email address in multiple users you can store it in `PrimaryEmail` which isn't validated or used in Authentication.